# rustc helloword.rs пишет "не найдена точка входа в ADVAPI32.DLL"

Tags: windows, rust, windows-xp

У меня win xp sp3.

Установил `rust-1.12.0-i686-pc-windows-gnu.msi`
Создал файлик `helloword.rs`.
Запустил Rust 1.12 (GNU) Shell

Пишу в командной строке: `rustc helloword.rs`

И получаю такое сообщение:

> точка входа в процедуру RegGetValueW не найдена в ADVAPI32.DLL

Эта dll-ка в системной папке есть. Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/getting-started.html#tier-3 - сами cargo/rustc на winxp не поддерживаются

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724868%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) данная процедура доступна только в 64-битной версии Windows XP.

Процитирую минимальные требования:

> Windows Vista, Windows XP Professional x64 Edition [desktop apps only]

Comment: ту снёс, поставил Rust beta 1.13 (GNU) Shell

Comment: всё то же самое, хотя выбрал 32 bit

Comment: @user224226, вы не поняли. Ваша операционная система не поддерживает эту версию Rust. У вас 32-битная, а нужна 64-битная.

Comment: да нет я понял.

Comment: https://www.rust-lang.org/ru-RU/downloads.html тут выбираю 32-bit

Comment: @user224226, повторяю еще раз, у вас Windows XP должна быть 64-битная, а не программа. С 32-битной версией Windows XP работать не будет.